# Mongodb group embedded objects

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this collection:

```
{
"_id" : "1",
"productGroup" : "G1",
"product" : {
    "oldPrice" : 1.22,
    "newPrice" : 1.33
    }
},
{
"_id" : "2",
"productGroup" : "G1",
"product" : {
     "oldPrice" : 1.12,
     "newPrice" : 1.23
    }
}
```

I want to group by **productGroup** and keep only the product having min **newPrice**
In my case it would be

```
{
"_id" : "G1",
"product" : {
   "oldPrice" : 1.12,
   "newPrice" : 1.23
   }
}
```

If I do this, I get only the newPrice property included while I need the whole product embedded object

```
db.myColl.aggregate([{
    "$group" : {
        _id : "$productGroup",
        product : { "$min" : "$product.newPrice"}
    }
}])
```

Any idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the aggregation pipeline use [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) and [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) to get the desired result of getting the minimum new price in each group.

```
db.myColl.aggregate([
    {$sort: {"product.newPrice":1}},
    {$group: {_id:"$productGroup", product:{$first:"$product"}}}
]);
```